# Send the binded (ng-model) data to Angularjs custome directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

/*what i want is 
     to set the maxDate as vmEndDate
*/

```
   app.directive('myDatepicker', function ($parse) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

            var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            alert(element.val());
            $(function(){
                element.datepicker({
                    showOn:"both",
                   // changeYear:true,
                    //changeMonth:true,
                    dateFormat:'dd-MMMM-yyyy',
                    //maxDate: vmEndDate,
                    minDate: new Date(),
                   // yearRange: '1920:2012',
                    onSelect:function (dateText, inst) {
                        scope.$apply(function(scope){
                            // Change binded variable
                            ngModel.assign(scope, dateText);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

/*html code */

```
 <input id="dp" type="text" ng-model="vmEndDate" name="mDate" my-datepicker/>
```

/*Aim: I want create a date picker (max and min ) using angular custom directive min is to day date and max date is vm end date (receiving from server )*/

Comment: What's the current output you're getting? Is it an error, is nothing showing up, or are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: when I used this line of code maxDate: vmEndDate in custom directive, in date picker nothing is happing.

Comment: why dont you use angular-ui datepicker, which has all this functionality build in

Comment: I tried to use the angular-ui datepicker it is not working in angular-ui modal.

Comment: Only first time the date picker is opened, but when I trying to select date from second time the angular-ui datepicker is not working in modal

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example,

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function ($parse) {

    return function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
        var vmEndDate = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);
        $(function () {
            element.datepicker({
                showOn: "both",
                // changeYear:true,
                //changeMonth:true,
                dateFormat: 'd-M-yy',
                maxDate: new Date(vmEndDate),
                minDate: new Date() ,
                // yearRange: '1920:2012',
                onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                    scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                        // Change binded variable
                        ngModel.assign(scope, dateText);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
});


    <input id="dp" type="text" ng-model="vmEndDate" ng-init="vmEndDate ='27-Feb-2015'" name="mDate" my-datepicker />
```